# Better way to check for updates (Server) and to save the updates in DB

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm developing a application in android. I have a server the show in JSON some datas and these data are updates many times. I need to build a app that check these datas and save them in database (Sqlite).

So, I'm reading how I would to do this, but I I'm newbie and I would like for some suggestions before I start to create the code.

- Use AsyncThread in background to check if exists any updates in server
- If exists any update, I will call a class to get the new data and save this data in database

Some like this:
http://codetheory.in/android-asynctask/ and
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/

That's a good way to do this?

Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app only needs to update the data while running this will be a good aproach...
Otherwise, application needs to update data also when not running, then you need another aproach.